# i keep getting "This password reset token is invalid"

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

i have laravel app which started on 4.2. Now it is 5.1.19.
I think i did update process as directed on laravel site.

Recently i noticed that i cannot reset password any more. (it was working somewhere around v5.0)

when user clicks on "forgotten pass", he recives email with link to reset, but after submitting form with new data: "This password reset token is invalid" error appears.

i checked DB, and password reset token is ok... (same as one POST sent in hidden field of password reset form)

can anyone help?

br
Y